# Array_combine more than 2 arrays from POST form

Tags: php

I need help combining arrays that I request using POST.

The html & php for the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="editservice2.php?id=<?=$id;?>">
<?php
while ($geti = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems)) {
?>
<input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="<?=$geti["id"];?>">
<input type="text" placeholder="Item name" value="<?=$geti["name"];?>" name="itemname[]">
<input type="text" style="width:40px;" placeholder="Item price" value="<?=$geti["price"];?>" name="itemprice[]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item description" value="<?=$geti["description"];?>" name="itemdesc[]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item image url" value="<?=$geti["imgurl"];?>" name="itemurl[]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item command" value="<?=$geti["command"];?>" name="itemcmd[]"><br><br>
<?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Configure items">
</form>
```

and the PHP after submiting:

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST["itemname"], $_POST["itemprice"]) as $itemname => $itemprice) {
    echo "Itemname: ".$itemname."<br>";
    echo "Itemprice: ".$itemprice."<br><br>";
}
```

However, the above code only works for 2  different values from the forum, how can I make it work for all 6 forms that I got?

Comment: Use the array indexes instead.

Comment: I'm not the best programmer out there, could I get an example of how that would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more robust way because it doesn't depend on the order the browser sends the key value pairs to the server. Additionally, it will work properly if you ever introduce optional field like checkboxes, which the browser doesnt send the name/value when its not "checked", which will ruin your indexing scheme. abbreviated example:

```
<input name="item[0][name]">
<input name="item[0][description]">
<input name="item[0][price]">

<input name="item[1][name]">
<input name="item[1][description]">
<input name="item[1][price]">

<input name="item[2][name]">
<input name="item[2][description]">
<input name="item[2][price]">
```

then

```
foreach ($_POST['items'] as $id => $associated_data) {
    echo $id, $associated_data['name'], $associated_data['price'], '...';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I chose you as the best answer because you had a nice and easy to understand code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge.
For complete reference and example please visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp
Tell me if your problem solved.

Comment: Yeah I saw Array_merge but I understand nothing, it seems complex to me for a weird reason

Comment: Use like below:    
array_merge($_POST["itemname"],  $_POST["itemprice"], $_POST["itemdesc"], $_POST["itemurl"] , $_POST["itemcmd"])

Comment: @Farouqxii Did you get now?

Comment: If you get answer to the question please upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: Could you please do one with an example? Like how would I get the same output as mine?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array('one'=>'TheOne');
$a2 = array('two'=>'TheTwo');
$a34 = array('three'=>'TheThree', 'four'=>'TheFour');
$a = $a1 + $a2 + $a34;

print_r($a);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [one] => TheOne
    [two] => TheTwo
    [three] => TheThree
    [four] => TheFour
)
```

So, you can use

```
foreach($a1+$a2+$a34 as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . "<br />";
}
```

Result :

```
one = TheOne
two = TheTwo
three = TheThree
four = TheFour
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XhpPFP)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare your array at the same time you are looping through it, try changing your code to this:

```
$item_names = array_combine($_POST["itemname"], $_POST["itemprice"]);
foreach ($item_names as $itemname => $itemprice) {
    echo "Itemname: ".$itemname."<br>";
    echo "Itemprice: ".$itemprice."<br><br>";
}
```

I would, however, set up this form in a different way. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][id]" value="<?=$geti["id"];?>">
<input type="text" placeholder="Item name" value="<?=$geti["name"];?>" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][name]">
<input type="text" style="width:40px;" placeholder="Item price" value="<?=$geti["price"];?>" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][price]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item description" value="<?=$geti["description"];?>" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][desc]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item image url" value="<?=$geti["imgurl"];?>" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][url]"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Item command" value="<?=$geti["command"];?>" name="items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][cmd]"><br><br>
```

Then in your handler do this:

```
$items = $_POST['items'];

foreach($items as $data){
    echo "Item ID: ".$data['id']."<br>";
    echo "Item Name: ".$data['name']."<br>";
    echo "Item Price: ".$data['price']."<br>";
    echo "Item Desc: ".$data['desc']."<br>";
    echo "Item IMG: ".$data['imgurl']."<br>";
    echo "Item CMD: ".$data['cmd']."<br><br>";
}
```

I would also suggest possibly refactoring your code for better readability. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you very much, however I don't really understand this part: "items[<?=$geti["id"];?>][name]" Mind elaborating? :)

Comment: By placing the item ID as the key in the array, you will now be able to add multiple items to that array. Each item then gets an id, name, price, etc. associated with it's ID instead of the array. That way your WHILE loop that is writing the fields, and the foreach loop in the handler both work properly.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: items in C:\xampp\htdocs\mineraft\base\editservice2.php on line 18
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mineraft\base\editservice2.php on line 20

Why am I getting those errors?

Comment: Ah sorry, you dont need the multi-dim section of the foreach. Check my post edit.